# node.js with readFile html but not loading/finding jquery file

Tags: jquery, html, node.js

I'm having trouble loading my jquery file or any file for that matter in a node.js read html file. I spent quite some time on this and noticed that the web based google hosted library file works fine, but my local file does not. I cannot figure out why, perhaps I'm not directing it to the correct directory, but I'm not sure where else I would put it or direct it.

Directory includes these 3 files

```
index.html
jquery.min.js
loadfile.js
```

index.html
The commented out google hosted jquery file works just fine. But the local does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                alert("test");
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi!
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the file I load with node. 
loadfile.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');


server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    current_url = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    file_path = __dirname + current_url;    

    var tmp = file_path.lastIndexOf('.');
    var ext = file_path.substring(tmp + 1);

    console.log(ext);

    if(ext == 'js')
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/javascript'});
    else if(ext == 'css')
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/css'});
    else
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});

    if(current_url == '/') {
        fs.readFile('index.html', 'utf8', function (errors, contents) {
            response.end(contents); 
        });
    } else {
        response.end();
    }

});

server.listen(8000);
console.log("Running in localhost at port 8000");
```

I get this error Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined on the $(document).ready line since it doesn't seem to think I loaded the jquery.

Any help would be appreciated. I could always use the google hosted file, but this doesn't sit well with me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't actually **serve the file** if the `current_url` isn't "/", right now your server can only send the file content of `index.html` to the client.

You need to have something like the following in your "else" clause:

```
fs.readFile(file_path, 'utf8', function (errors, contents) {
    response.end(contents); 
});
```