# Import jquery files to html file in nodejs

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

My index.html file is like shown below

```
  <html>
   <body>

    <script src="public/jquery-latest-min.js"></script>
     /*But this script file is not importing and creating error */        

   </body>
 </html>
```

app.js code is

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
    server.listen(3000);

     app.get('/',function(req, res){
         res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
     });
```

How can the index.html file can serve the jquery file located in public folder.

And my project structure is:

```
             |-index.html
             |-app.js
             |-public/jquery-latest-min.js
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17247319/node-js-with-readfile-html-but-not-loading-finding-jquery-file

Answer (score 1):

The following can be used to serve static files such as javascript files or CSS files.

```
var server = express(); // better instead
server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Comment: I just added the line   server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); but not working

Comment: Yes so it should work now. Note that i have used a different variable for `express()` than yours. Change it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure *static* files as per @anubhav suggested.

Then you can reference your files like below.

```
<script src="jquery-latest-min.js"></script>
```

You should not use absolute path rather just to reference path which are relative to *static* folders like *public* in your case.